# Log4J2 and ApachePDFBox getting error Message "No appenders"

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2, pdfbox

Im using PdfBox 1.7.0 and Log4j 2.0-beta4.

The L4j2 configuration is saved als xml in "resources\Log4j2.xml" (Project in maven)
Here is the conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF" packages="">
    <appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>

        <logger name="org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine" level="trace">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>
        <root level="debug">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

I added the "logger", but the warning is still here:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

how should i configure L4J? Is there a obvious thing i don't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a test with your configuration using Log4j2 beta5, and I could not reproduce the problem. Looks like this was fixed in beta 5.

Beta5 has some new goodies (Async Loggers, JMX, JSP taglib) btw, maybe worth to check it out.

Comment: It only just came out. But check out the performance of Async Loggers.